# calculate sum of 5 integers 12345 to print using java

Tags: java

I am so very new to coding and forgive me if this very basic question has been answered however when searching I still cannot see what is missing from my code. I am simply trying to get the sum of 5 integers. I can get it to print the integers however it just runs after that and never gives the answer. What is it waiting for me to do or what is my code missing? I have no errors so I am just not seeing what is wrong.

```
System.out.print("Please enter 5 integers: ");
    int arr = input.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int a = 1; a <= 100; a++){
        arr = input.nextInt();
    }
    sum = sum + arr;
    System.out.println("The sum of 5 integers is: " + sum);
```

Comment: change the loop condition to `for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){...`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.out.print("Please enter 5 integers: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){
      sum += input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("The sum of 5 integers is: " + sum);
```